# MS word Ctrl+Backspace changes style unwantedly

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

This might be a rare and confusing problem but I hope someone experienced with context texts can aid the issue's solution. I type in MS Word 2013 context texts i.e. Persian mixed with English. In Normal style, I have specified font X for Latin text and font Y for context text. For example:

> این یک کتاب (book) است

So I have right to left and left to right text interleaved. There is a casual weird issue that I'm having with Word in that it forgets the style (e.g. Normal) that I was using once I press ctrl+backspace to delete a word. That is it assumes the style for Latin text whereas I meant to write the rest of my Persian rtl text. This is really annoying because I have to frequently change the font to match the style I intended for my Persian text.

Update: To clarify what was stated above, I add that once I press ctrl+space to delete the last word, Word assumes the font meant in Normal style for Latin text whereas the text being typed is context and Word is expected to use the font specified in Normal Style for context texts.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is where MS-Word keeps the style.  It seems that deleting can delete the formatting, which is hiding at the end of the word.

I abandoned word because it does a lot of things behind my back, this one of them.

Comment: What alternative are you using now @wendy.krieger?

Comment: I use open office, if i could.  It produces smaller files, and smaller output (eg the pdf files are smaller), because OO correctly implements styles.